# Powershell - Add mailbox account to Outlook

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, ms-office

I have googled tons for this but with no success, maybe I just have the wrong approach?

**Problem:**
We work with migrating organizations from on premises Exchange to Office 365 and vice versa. As a service we also log in to all user computers and do the initial "add existing mailbox"-steps. Since we are using Autodiscovery-pointers this takes a lot of time. With a bad bandwidth it can take up to 15 min per user.

**Our goal:**
Create a Powershelscript where we can put the settings that normally being fetched by Autodiscovery and quickly add a new, existing mailbox to the computer so next time they log in they can just start the Outlook application and they are logged in.

I hope I made myself understandable, please ask if anything is unclear.
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Maybe there is a way to go through the initial Outlook-setup via a PSSession? Then the time that an Autodiscovery takes wouldn't matter since we can do all the setups remote, unatended.